# Value not getting pass from variable in string in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a For loop in plsql and a procedure.
Inside the procedure I have IF block :

```
 IF c.payer='GCC' and  c.dataset='SAME' then
EMPID:=REGEXP_SUBSTR(c.hitablename,'[^_]+',1,4);
vbquery:='                          
Insert /*parallel(unk_codes)*/ into unk_codes(act_nbr, hitablename, groupid, payer)
select /* parallel(a,4) */ distinct '''||EMPID||'0100'' as  unknown_codes,'''||c.hitablename||''' as hitablename,
REGEXP_SUBSTR('''||c.hitablename||''',''[^_]+'',1,4) as groupid,'''||c.payer||''' as payer  from HI0777777.'||c.hitablename||' a
where '''||EMPID||'0100'' in  (select NVL(b.ACC_NUM,''NOT'') from group_abc b where
'''||EMPID||'0100'' = b.ACC_NUM
        AND
REGEXP_SUBSTR('''||c.hitablename||''',''[^_]+'',1,4)=b.group_id)';
BEGIN                   
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vbquery;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN       
Dbms_Output.put_line('GCC SAME block'||SQLERRM||vbquery||c.ai_table);
END;
END IF;
```

I want to pass EMPID inside the **vbquery** string but I am getting `ORA-00936: missing expression` error.
I tried to debugged and see what is the problem and I found EMPID value not getting replaced inside vbquery.

My **vbquery** is being printed as:

```
 ORA-00936: missing expression                                                                     
Insert /*parallel(unk_codes)*/ into unk_codes(act_nbr, hitablename, groupid, payer)
select /* parallel(a,4) */ distinct  unknown_codes,'HI_SAME_GCC_MPD' as hitablename,
REGEXP_SUBSTR('HI_SAME_GCC_MPD','[^_]+',1,4) as groupid,'GCC' as payer  from HI0777777.HI_SAME_GCC_MPD a
where not exists (select 1 from group_abc b where b.acc_num= and
REGEXP_SUBSTR('HI_SAME_GCC_MPD','[^_]+',1,4)=b.group_id)
```

My EMPID may be **'ABCD'.**
So my expected output was:

```
  Insert /*parallel(unk_codes)*/ into unk_codes(act_nbr, hitablename, groupid, payer)
    select /* parallel(a,4) */ distinct  'ABCD0100' unknown_codes,'HI_SAME_GCC_MPD' as hitablename,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR('HI_SAME_GCC_MPD','[^_]+',1,4) as groupid,'GCC' as payer  from HI0777777.HI_SAME_GCC_MPD a
    where not exists (select 1 from group_abc b where b.acc_num='ABCD0100' and
    REGEXP_SUBSTR('HI_SAME_GCC_MPD','[^_]+',1,4)=b.group_id)
```

Why is that EMPID value not getting passed in string?

Comment: In the vbquery example it is not only EMPID missing but '''0100' as" is missing too. Is it just a mistake in the example or they are really missing?

Comment: @ekochergin yes it is reallt missing. I dont know why it is missing

Comment: ps @AshwinKarki - sorry to mislead, I was wrong having tried it out now, so I have deleted my answer.  eg `DECLARE
    v_test  VARCHAR2(4000);
    v_test2 VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN

    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('500 Oracle Parkway, Redwood Shores, CA',
                         ',[^,]+,')
    INTO v_test2
    FROM dual;

    v_test := REGEXP_SUBSTR('500 Oracle Parkway, Redwood Shores, CA',
                            ',[^,]+,');
    dbms_output.put_line(v_test);
    dbms_output.put_line(v_test2);

END;` - both outputs show up fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking in a wrong place in code. In the plsql-example I see the following part in the query you're trying to build

```
... where '''||EMPID||'0100'' in  (select NVL(b.ACC_NUM,''NOT'') from group_abc b where...
```

but in the debug result of your query there is a part which is completely different and shouldn't be there at all

```
... where not exists (select 1 from group_abc b where b.acc_num= and ...
```

I'm pretty sure there is another branch in the "if" or something similar to that

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what values are involved so I tried to guess; also, I don't have your tables so I *skipped* a loop and used local variables instead.

It seems that either

- `c.hitablename` doesn't look as you think it does, or
- `REGEXP_SUBSTR` (which is used to set EMPID's value) doesn't work as you think it does as it returns an empty string, not e.g. `ABCD` (as you expected)

Because, if `hitablename` is something like in my example (`X_Y_Z_ABCD`), then the final `insert` statement looks OK:

---

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> DECLARE
  2     c_hitablename  VARCHAR2 (20) := 'X_Y_Z_ABCD';   --> this isn't what you think it is ...
  3     c_payer        VARCHAR2 (20) := 'xxxx';
  4     EMPID          VARCHAR2 (20);
  5     vbquery        VARCHAR2 (1000);
  6  BEGIN
  7     EMPID :=                                        --> ... or this doesn't do what you think it does
  8        REGEXP_SUBSTR (c_hitablename,
  9                       '[^_]+',
 10                       1,
 11                       4);
 12     vbquery :=
 13           '
 14  Insert /*parallel(unk_codes)*/ into unk_codes(act_nbr, hitablename, groupid, payer)
 15  select /* parallel(a,4) */ distinct '''
 16        || EMPID
 17        || '0100'' as  unknown_codes,'''
 18        || c_hitablename
 19        || ''' as hitablename,
 20  REGEXP_SUBSTR('''
 21        || c_hitablename
 22        || ''',''[^_]+'',1,4) as groupid,'''
 23        || c_payer
 24        || ''' as payer  from HI0777777.'
 25        || c_hitablename
 26        || ' a
 27  where '''
 28        || EMPID
 29        || '0100'' in  (select NVL(b.ACC_NUM,''NOT'') from group_abc b where
 30  '''
 31        || EMPID
 32        || '0100'' = b.ACC_NUM
 33          AND
 34  REGEXP_SUBSTR('''
 35        || c_hitablename
 36        || ''',''[^_]+'',1,4)=b.group_id)';
 37
 38     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (vbquery);
 39  END;
 40  /

Insert /*parallel(unk_codes)*/ into unk_codes(act_nbr, hitablename, groupid,
payer)
select /* parallel(a,4) */ distinct 'ABCD0100' as
unknown_codes,'X_Y_Z_ABCD' as
hitablename,
REGEXP_SUBSTR('X_Y_Z_ABCD','[^_]+',1,4) as groupid,'xxxx' as payer
from HI0777777.X_Y_Z_ABCD a
where 'ABCD0100' in  (select NVL(b.ACC_NUM,'NOT')
from group_abc b where
'ABCD0100' = b.ACC_NUM

AND
REGEXP_SUBSTR('X_Y_Z_ABCD','[^_]+',1,4)=b.group_id)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Formatted:

```
INSERT                                                 /*parallel(unk_codes)*/
       INTO unk_codes (act_nbr,
                       hitablename,
                       groupid,
                       payer)
   SELECT                                                  /* parallel(a,4) */
          DISTINCT 'ABCD0100' AS unknown_codes,
                   'X_Y_Z_ABCD' AS hitablename,
                   REGEXP_SUBSTR ('X_Y_Z_ABCD',
                                  '[^_]+',
                                  1,
                                  4) AS groupid,
                   'xxxx' AS payer
     FROM HI0777777.X_Y_Z_ABCD a
    WHERE 'ABCD0100' IN (SELECT NVL (b.ACC_NUM, 'NOT')
                           FROM group_abc b
                          WHERE     'ABCD0100' = b.ACC_NUM
                                AND REGEXP_SUBSTR ('X_Y_Z_ABCD',
                                                   '[^_]+',
                                                   1,
                                                   4) = b.GROUP_ID)
```

---

Finally: what do you think those `/*parallel(unk_codes)*/` *thingies* do? I bet you thought query will run *faster* if you executed it with that **hint**, didn't you? Bad news for you - what you put in here is just a **comment**, not a hint. Oracle suggests us (developers) not to use hints if we don't know what they do and how to properly use them. You, apparently, don't as you made the same mistake **twice** (so it wasn't a typo). Therefore, you can remove those comments out of your code (or use a hint if you really want to, but then use proper syntax).